# Resize c array of structs to hold another struct

Tags: c

I have a c struct defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    int data_size;          
    BYTE* data;
} IMAGE;
```

I have another struct like this

```
typedef struct
{
    int nimages;
    IMAGE* images;
} IMGARR
```

I would like to be able to reallocate `images` to hold another `sizeof(IMAGE)` structure so I can just keep an array of images with their binary data.

Here is what I've been trying

```
IMGARR* image_temp = imgarr->images; //store pointer
image_temp = realloc(&image_temp, (imgarr->nimages + 1) * sizeof(IMAGE)); //realloc memory
memcpy(&imgarr->images[imgarr->nimages], &my_new_image, sizeof(IMAGE));
```

This doesn't seem to work at all. I seem to have become really rusty at c memory allocation. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Your use of types and variable names is a little bit confusing. Is `imgarr` of type `IMGARR*`? Is `imgarr-images` of type `IMAGE*`?

Comment: that is pretty confusing I see that now. I think I have fixed my problem, I'll post an update when I'm able to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Right way to do this is:

```
IMGARR* image_temp = realloc(imgarr->images, (n+1) * sizeof(IMAGE)); /* n = New size */
if(image_temp != NULL)
imgarr->images = image_temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not changed what `imgarr->images` points to. Check `image_temp` for `NULL` but if you got the space then reassign `->images` before attempting to write to it.

Also, no need for the `memcpy`. Direct assignments of structs is allowed.